# function to change dates does not work

Tags: javascript, function, date, weekend

With a lot of help I've done a function that checks onload if a date is a weekend or not, and if it is a sunday it must increment the day. If it is a Saturday it day has 2 added to it because unfortunately in France nobody wants to work during the weekend.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdate() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
        }



        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
            var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
            if (itemDt.getDay() == 6) {

                itemCount[i].value =  itemDt.getDate()+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();


            }
            if (itemDt.getDay() == 0) {

               itemCount[i].value = itemDt.getDate()+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();

            }

        }
       return items;
  }
</script>
```

All works fine for checking if date is a weekend but when I'm asking date +1 it does not change.

I just would like to change Saturday and Sunday to Monday.

Thanks for the help

SP.

Comment: Is this 'date' the current day or a date from an element(s) `.date` or `#date`? Can you post the (relevant) html, or a url?

Comment: dear Sir here is the revelant:  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)): ?>  <td>  <input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][date]" class="date" id="date<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php 


echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['date_action'])) ;

 ?>" size="12"></td>

Comment: the concern is that days are changing to monday but one second after theyu turn back to their original days

Comment: can you post some test HTML and the js into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you do:

```
> var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
```

you can then do something like:

```
// Increment date if Saturday or Sunday
var inc = itemDt.getDay() == 0? 1 : itemDt.getDay() == 6? 2 : 0;

// Only update DOM if necessary
if (inc) {
  itemDt.setDate(itemDt.getDate() + inc);
  // Update DOM
}
```

Note that Date objects adjust if the date is set beyond the end of the month (or before the start), so setting a date of 32 January becomes 1 February.

Comment: dear Sir, I've tried your function but it does not work, and ther eis no mistakes